# How to pass an object to a select element as a data type and make it readable to use it somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

The thing is that I have this select element with some options:

```js
  {result.map(({ question }) => (
    <option key={question.id} value={question.id} data-type={question.type} data-question={question}>
      {question.title}
    </option>
  ))}
```

If I get the data set question, I get this:

```
console.log({ questionItSelf: JSON.stringify(getSelectedOption.dataset.question) })
// {questionItSelf: "\"[object Object]\""}
```

[image]

How can I get those values to use them in another place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to pass data through the `data-` attribute you could stringify your data before passing it. Since I think it only accepts primitive values.

```
data-question={JSON.stringify(question)}
```

and then parse it again when you want to use it:

```
console.log({ questionItSelf: JSON.parse(getSelectedOption.dataset.question) })
```

### Addition

I would personally avoid this. If you could briefly tell us what you are trying to do, maybe someone could come up with a more "React" way of doing this.

Comment: I am just trying to get some properties from that object to use them somewhere else. I am using react hook form and a select element: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register